# Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (32,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train a Keras model where a singular input is a normalized array of floats of length 512. I currently have 539 of these inputs in my training data, but the following error is produced as soon as the `predict()` method is called:

```
Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (32,)
```

And here is the code, note I've tried passing different shapes to the `Input()` based on suggestions I found on other posts such as `Input(Shape=(1,))` and `Input(Shape=(512,))` but neither of these worked.

```
X = np.array(X)  #(539, 512)
y = np.array(y)  #(539,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(None, 512)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=4, validation_split=0.1, epochs=5)

prediction = model.predict([X[0]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the model is expecting you the batch_size also try this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(512)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=4, validation_split=0.1, epochs=5)
```

Now, for predict expand the dimension for batch-size

```
prediction = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(X[0], axis=0))
```

Output

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 119ms/step
```